# Segmentation fault while trying to print parts of a pointer struct

Tags: struct, fault

I'm writing a program that must take user input to assign values to parts of a structure. I need to create a pointer to the structure that I will pass through as a one and only parameter for a function that will print each part of the structure individually. I also must malloc memory for the structure. As it is now, the program compiles and runs through main and asks the user for inputs. A segmentation fault occurs after the last user input is collected and when I'm assuming the call to the printContents function is run. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct info
{
        char name[100], type;
        int size;
        long int stamp;
};

void printContents(struct info *iptr);

int main(void)
{
        struct info *ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct info));

                printf("Enter the type: \n");
                scanf("%c", &(*ptr).type);
                printf("Enter the filename: \n");
                scanf("%s", (*ptr).name);
                printf("Enter the access time: \n");
                scanf("%d", &(*ptr).stamp);
                printf("Enter the size: \n");
                scanf("%d", &(*ptr).size);

        printf("%c", (*ptr).type);

        printContents(ptr);

}

void printContents(struct info *iptr)
{

        printf("Filename %s Size %d Type[%s] Accessed @ %d \n", (*iptr).name, (*iptr).size, (*iptr).type, (*iptr).stamp);

}
```

Comment: After I edit the code to rectify the compile warnings, it runs without error. The compiler is your friend.

Comment: What code do you edit? It compiles just fine for me? I can run the program and then after the user input is collected, a segmentation fault occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the operator precedence. Is this `&(*ptr).type` the thing you're trying to do? Maybe `&((*ptr).type)` ?

Comment: I'm trying to store the values into the struct and create a pointer to it. Should I not use pointers at all in the scanf? I'm unsure about how to make a pointer to a struct.

Comment: See Beta's reply. He found out the reason. The problem has nothing to do with precedence, sorry for misleading you. The problem was that you're using `%s` where char variable `type` comes. As a result, the program takes the VALUE of `type` as base address for the string, and because the value is between 0 and 255, the program tries to access memory address between 0 and 255, hence we have an error. You should replace `Type[%s]` in `printContents` by `Type[%c]`

Answer (score 0):

ptr->member is like access to structure variable right? Also same for scanf() usr &ptr->member to get value. For char input use only ptr->charmember .

Answer (score 0):

**First let's do it the hard way.** We'll assume that the code is already written, the compiler tells us nothing useful, and we don't have a debugger. First we put in some diagnostic output statements, and we discover that the crash happens in `printContents`:

```
printf("testing four\n"); /* we see this, so the program gets this far */
printf("Filename %s Size %d Type[%s] Accessed @ %d \n", (*iptr).name, (*iptr).size, (*iptr).type, (*iptr).stamp);
printf("testing five\n"); /* the program crashes before this */
```

If we still can't see the bug, we narrow the problem down by preparing a [minimal compete example](http://sscce.org). (This is a very valuable skill.) We compile and run the code over and over, commenting things out. When we comment something out and the code still segfaults, we remove it entirely; but if commenting it out makes the problem go away, we *put it back in*. Eventually we get down to a minimal case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char type;

  type = 'a';

  printf("Type[%s]\n", type);
}
```

Now it should be obvious: when we `printf("%s", x)` something, `printf` expects `x` to be a *string*. That is, `x` should be a pointer to (i.e. the address of) the first element of a character array which ends with a null character. Instead we've given it a character (in this case 'a'), which it interprets as a number (in this case 97), and it tries to go to that address in memory and start reading; **we're lucky to get nothing worse than a segfault.** The fix is easy: decide whether `type` should be a `char` or a `char[]`, if it's `char` then change the `printf` statement to "%c", if it's `char[]` then change its declaration.

**Now an easy way.** If we're using a good compiler like gcc, it will warn us that we're doing something fishy:

```
gcc foo.c -o foo
foo.c:35: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’
```

In future, there's a way you can save yourself all this trouble. Instead of writing a lot of code, getting a mysterious bug and backtracking, you can write in small increments. If you had added one term to that `printf` statement at a time, you would have seen exactly when the bug appeared, and which term was to blame.

Remember: start small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, test at every step, and *never add to code that doesn't work.*